# Replace seconds on setting input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, replace, onclick

I have this click function to set multiple input values. For some of them I need to convert the val from seconds into hh:mm:ss.

```
jQuery('#pressnew').on('click', function() {
    
    var api = flowplayer('#jet-tabs-content-1381 .flowplayer');

    jQuery("#input1").val(api.video.time);
    jQuery("#input2").val(api.get_ab_end);
    

});


function formatTime(secs) {
    let h = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    let m = Math.floor(secs % 3600 / 60);
    let s = Math.floor(secs % 3600 % 60);
    if (h > 0) {       
        return (("0" + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2));     
    }   

    else {    
         return (("0" + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + s).slice(-2)); 
    };   
}
```

The api calls returning seconds as int. The question is how can I pass the seconds from my api calls to the formatTime function and set the returned value as value for my input fields?

Comment: `.text()` returns a **String**. Why do you use Reminder Operator `d % 3600` on a string? Do you remember how to convert a String to Number?

Comment: What is `this` in your first snippet `var d = jQuery(this).text();` ? Does `this` refers to some element? Window? Can you improve your question and code? Read: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Lets me try this with some assumptions - Since what you actually want, is not clear from your question.
You have a snippet which is taking a text(which is time info in seconds) and converting it into H:M:S.
Now you have some element(id: Add Marker) which when you click gives you a value in seconds, you want to convert this into H:M:S format and set this as value of some text element having class (current_time).

- So You can first of all wrap the conversion code in a function which inputs a number and returns a string(H:M:S)
- Inside click handler of element, take value of the second inside a variable and **make sure you convert it to int**
- call your function and pass value from step 2 and store return string in a variable
- Set the value of the input element to value from step 3.

Feel free to correct if there is some gap in understanding

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. I'm at the beginning of my java journey and it is still often hard to follow or better understand instructions, even If I think that's exactly what I need. I managed to get a working function now, maybe you could have a look again.

Comment: Okay, so assuming that api.video.time is giving you a number in seconds, just do either this jQuery("#input1").val(formatTime(api.video.time)), or let time_str = formatTime(api.video.time); jQuery("#input1").val(time_str)